# Mapbox style like FourSquare

Tags: css, mapbox

I am working on an interactive map, considering to use Mapbox, and I would like to have the foursquare style as a base, so I can edit it from there since I dont like the initial styles of Mabpox Studio. Here is the example of the map:

https://www.mapbox.com/bites/00032/#11/32.7506/-16.9766

The question is, how can I copy the styles of this foursquare map to my current Map in Mapbox?

```
// Example code
#landuse[zoom>=11] {
  polygon-fill: #c2f250;
  line-width: 0.5;
  line-color: #615f5f;
}

#roadlabel[zoom>=11] {
  line-width: 3.5;
  line-color: #c02525;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [any of Mapbox's ready-to-use maps](https://www.mapbox.com/maps/#ready-to-use) with one click.

The Foursquare style, on the other hand, is not for usage outside of Foursquare: it is a copyrighted artwork designed and licensed exclusively for Foursquare.